# Помогите сделать чтоб все объекты исчезли

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Кода я пытаюсь скрыть объекты из окна, в консоль выдается ошибка и объекты больше не скрываются, что нужно изменить?
Суть когда в том что он должен кодировать строчку, и при нажатии radiobuton("Conventor") все объекты кроме переключателей должны исчезнуть, при нажатии Coder наоборот высветиться.

Ошибка: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.title("coder")
win.geometry("300x300")
win.minsize(width=300, height=300)
win.maxsize(width=300, height=300)

def coder():
    sim = ""
    exi = ""
    top = ""
    sop = int(str(setin.get()))
    top = word.get()
    lop = 0
    ogr = 0
    ogr = len(top) 
    while ogr > lop:
        sim = ord(top[lop])
        sim = sim + sop
        sim = chr(sim)
        exi=(exi + sim)
        lop = lop + 1
tex.delete("all")
tex.create_text(130, 130, text=exi, font="Centaur")

def uncoder():
    sim = ""
    exi = ""
    top = ""
    sop = int(str(setin.get()))
    top = word.get()
    lop = 0
    ogr = 0
    ogr = len(top)
    while ogr > lop:
        sim = ord(top[lop])
        sim = sim - sop
        sim = chr(sim)
        exi=(exi + sim)
        lop = lop + 1
    tex.delete("all")
    tex.create_text(130, 130, text=exi, font="Centaur")

def conv():
    obj = [U, V, enter, seting]
    for name in obj:
        name.grid()
    sot.delete("all")

def coder1():
    U.place(relx=.200, rely=.300, anchor="w")
    V.place(relx=.478, rely=.300, anchor="w")
    enter.place(relx=.200, rely=.100, anchor="w")
    seting.place(relx=.200, rely=.150, anchor="w")
    sot.create_text(40, 30, text="Enter:", font="Centaur")
    sot.create_text(35, 45, text="Setting:", font="Centaur")


sot = Canvas(win, width=300, height=53)
sot.pack()

tex = Canvas(win, width=300, height=140)
tex.pack()

word = StringVar()
enter = Entry(textvariable=word)
setin = StringVar()
seting = Entry(textvariable=setin)

U = Button(win, text="uncoder", command=uncoder)
V = Button(win, text="coder", command=coder)

lang = IntVar()

C = Radiobutton(win, text="Conventor", value=2, variable=lang, command=conv)
C.place(relx=.720, rely=.80, anchor="w")
P = Radiobutton(win, text="Coder", value=1, variable=lang, command=coder1)
P.place(relx=.720, rely=.70, anchor="w")


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Егор\Desktop\program\CoderCopy.py", line 48, in conv
    name.grid()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2223, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Comment: Согласно [документации](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) на Tkinter не следует использовать менеджеры grid и pack в одном родительском окне. В функции `conv()` у Вас используется `grid`, в то время как в остальном коде используется `pack`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) на Tkinter не следует использовать менеджеры `grid` и `pack` в одном родительском окне. В функции `conv()` у Вас используется `grid`, в то время как в остальном коде используется `pack`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы виджеты скрывались при выборе "Converter" следует в функции `conv()` заменить `name.grid()` на `name.place_forget()`. Полный код функции:

```
def conv():
    obj = [U, V, enter, seting]
    for name in obj:
        name.place_forget()
    sot.delete("all")
```